# How to change colour of only used borders in html table?

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown, stargazer

I have this table in my Rmd presentation:

[image]

that was obtained doing `stargazer(fit, type = "html")`

I tried to include css in my Rmd like:

`table, th, td {border: 1px solid white;}`

And the result is:

[image]

I want to re-colour just actually used borders. Like this (photoshop edited):

[image]

My idea is to do this using css because I have more than 40 tables. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're just wanting to change the colors?
Try just using the `border-color` property, otherwise adding size and type will create a new border. So for example,

```
table, th, td {
  border-color: white;
}
```

Comment: the trick is to add `important` like: `table, th, td {border-color: white!important;}`